# How to define a table with colored sections

Tags: tables, longtable

I need to write a table like the image below in Latex.
[image]

**This table represents the data structure of a message**, which some specific data of the message and other fields that are inserted into two datastructure (section A and section B).
Each section has also an other nested subsection (respectively subsection A.1 and subsection B.1).

Each row contains three column: Field, Type, Description.

**I began writing the table without the nested section:**

```
\begin{longtable}{p{5cm}p{1cm}p{6cm}}

% didascalia ed etichetta
\caption{caption name}
\label{tab:name of table} \\

% intestazione iniziale
\toprule
\textbf{Field} &\textbf{Type} &\textbf{Description}\\

\midrule
\endfirsthead
% intestazione normale
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize\itshape\tablename~\thetable:
continued from previous page} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Field} &\textbf{Type} &\textbf{Description}\\

\midrule
\endhead
% piede normale
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape\tablename~\thetable:
Continued on next page} \\
\endfoot
% piede finale
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape\tablename~\thetable:
si conclude dalla pagina precedente} \\
\endlastfoot

% corpo della tabella

field\_name &   String  &   description of some rows    \\

\end{longtable}
```

**My questions are:**

1. What is the best way to represent the nested sections into a Latex Table?
2. I wrote the table in the image by MS Excel: section A and setion B are done with the union of cells of that row. How can I obtain a similar result in Latex?

Thank you in advance for your help and collaboration!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't insist on a real table, it can be done quite easily with *TikZ*. It has the mayor downside that it will fail with multiline text, but you can specify an optional parameter to give a line some extra space. It does not break across pages.

### Code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\ypos}{0}
\newcommand{\ysep}{0.6}
\newcommand{\widthA}{5}
\newcommand{\widthB}{3.5}
\newcommand{\widthC}{8}
\newcommand{\colSep}{0.25}
\newcommand{\boxWidth}{1}

\newcommand{\Line}[4][0]%
{   \node[below right, text width=\widthA*1cm, align=left, inner sep=1mm] at (0,\ypos) {#2};
    \node[below right, text width=\widthB*1cm, align=left, inner sep=1mm] at (\widthA+\colSep,\ypos) {#3};
    \node[below right, text width=\widthC*1cm, align=left, inner sep=1mm] at (\widthA+\widthB+2*\colSep,\ypos) {#4};
    \pgfmathparse{\ypos-\ysep-#1}
    \xdef\ypos{\pgfmathresult}
}

\newcommand{\Heading}[2]%
{   \node[below right, text width={(\widthA+\widthB+\widthC+2*\colSep)*1cm-2.5mm}, align=left, fill=#1, inner sep=1.25mm] at (0,\ypos) {#2};
    \pgfmathparse{\ypos-\ysep}
    \xdef\ypos{\pgfmathresult}
}

\newcommand{\StartColorBox}[1]%
% color
{   \xdef\BoxColor{#1}
    \xdef\BoxStart{\ypos}
    \pgfmathparse{\ypos-\ysep}
    \xdef\ypos{\pgfmathresult}
}

\newcommand{\EndColorBox}%
% color
{   \fill[\BoxColor, yshift=-\ysep*1cm](0,\BoxStart) -| ++ (\widthA+\widthB+\widthC+2*\colSep,\ysep) -| ($(0,\ypos)+(-\boxWidth,0)$) -| ++ (\boxWidth+\widthA+\widthB+\widthC+2*\colSep,\ysep) -| cycle;
    \pgfmathparse{\ypos-\ysep}
    \xdef\ypos{\pgfmathresult}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Line{field\_name}{type}{description}
    \Line{field\_name}{type}{description}
    \StartColorBox{blue!50!gray}
        \Heading{green!50!gray!50}{SECTION X: Lorem ipsum}
            \Line{field\_name}{type}{description}
            \Line{field\_name}{type}{description}
            \Line{field\_name}{type}{description}
        \Heading{orange!50!gray!50}{SECTION X: Lorem ipsum}
            \Line{field\_name}{type}{description}
            \Line{field\_name}{type}{description}
    \EndColorBox
    \StartColorBox{red!50!gray}
        \Heading{green!50!gray!50}{SECTION X: Lorem ipsum}
            \Line[0.45]{field\_name}{type}{description description description description description}
            \Line{field\_name}{type}{description}
            \Line{field\_name}{type}{description}
            \Line{field\_name}{type}{description}
            \Line{field\_name}{type}{description}
            \Line{field\_name}{type}{description}
        \Heading{orange!50!gray!50}{SECTION X: Lorem ipsum}
            \Line{field\_name}{type}{description}
            \Line{field\_name}{type}{description}
            \Line{field\_name}{type}{description}
            \Line{field\_name}{type}{description}
    \EndColorBox
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]